# Use /src/resources as source directory for a new package

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft-forge

I would like to create a new package in Inteliji IDEA (Community Edition) where the source directory is /src/main/resources. I am trying to create a simple forge mod, and need to create several packages in resources for handling textures and other assets. My file structure looks like this:

```
Main
>Java
 >com.mycompany.project
  >Package1
  >Package2
  >Main.java
Resources
 >mcmod.info
 >pack.mcmeta
```

Is there any way to create a package in /src/main/resources? I have seen examples of this being done in Eclipse, but I would prefer to not have to use two IDEs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-running-your-first-java-application.html#create-package-and-class).

I believe you can do it by right clicking on `Resources` folder, then `New` -> `Directory` and then specify the package `com.mycompany.project`. Intellij will create the hierarchical package structure.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I didn't know if IDEA defined directories and packages differently.